# Spring Kotlin Bean DSL - register bean only if other bean is present?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, spring5, spring-bean-dsl

I want to register bean (`MyBean`) only if another bean (`anotherBeanThatShouldBePresent`) is present in the context.

How I can achieve that?

```
bean {
    MyBean(
        anotherBeanThatShouldBePresent = ref()
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [ObjectProvider](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/ObjectProvider.html) to create bean depending on another bean

```
bean {
    provider<OtherBeanOnWhichIDepend>().ifAvailable {
        bean<MyCustomBean>()
    }
}
```

With this code I will register MyCustomBean only if OtherBeanOnWhichIDepend bean is available